# how to change Android reside menu item's textsize?

Tags: android

I used Android reside menu. But this menu items are very big for my application, I want to set smaller item. How can i do this. Thanks for you attention!

Comment: What is a "reside menu"?

Comment: You can know more info about reside menu on this link. https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

Answer (score 0):

Get the source of the Reside menu
Edit the  ResideMenuItem (ImageView iv_icon,TextView tv_title) object to your respective shape  & size

Comment: You means I must to change icon and text size when I create Reside meni items.